# AWS : How to switch as "root" user?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, root, rhel-6

I have new created EC2 instance in aws, and able to login as EC2-user using private key but want to login as root to install packages. Not able to switch as root tried sudo - but it asking for password, I didn't creat any password for root yet. I am stuck here

Comment: Check this [guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/set-change-root-linux/).

Comment: It's working now, need to create password for root by typing "passwd" command and set password for root

Comment: Post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now, need to create password for root by typing "passwd" command and set password for root. To switch user "su root" command.

Answer (score 10):

For Amazon Linux 2 you can use `sudo su`

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ~]$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"

[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ~]$ sudo su

[root@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ec2-user]# whoami
root
```